# Customize Liferay 7.0.2 GA3 core DB Column Sizes

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I need to extend `Organization.name` from `VARCHAR(100)` to `VARCHAR(200)`.

I'm working on Liferay 7.0.2 GA3.

There is some mechanism to override `liferay-portal/portal-impl/src/META-INF/portal-model-hints.xml`?

Or perhaps something else that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the core database structure is discouraged and will create an unmaintainable mess: There might be parts which assume the current length (even though I'd hope there aren't). In general it's discouraged to look at the database structure and content anyway.

That being said, I'd be curious to learn about the usecase to use organizations with a name that long. Imagine: In addition to your maintenance tasks for future Liferay upgrades, this would create a real display issue on the UI: The organization name might appear in several places (e.g. if that organization has a site attached to it). How would you intend to display those names in a way that doesn't totally break the UI?

Or, to summarize: Don't go there. Introduce organizational rules to use shorter organization names. IMHO even 100 characters is waaaay too long to be of practical use.

Also, as you prefer to [ask in multiple places](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/86896668), generating the same work multiple times: [Don't do this in future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site).

Comment: I'm working on university portal that was born with Liferay 5 and after was migrated to liferay 6 and 6.1

Now i'm migrating it to Liferay 7. We use Organization like courses. Courses some time have very long title like "[2016-17] - RETI DI COMUNICAZIONE E INTERNET (PER INGEGNERIA INFORMATICA) [ INGEGNERIA INFORMATICA ]" 

I'm sorry for dublicate question.